# Fill remaining height in such a way as height: 100% works inside

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, css

Consider this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SD4nM/4/

In Firefox and Chrome there are no scroll bars; the innermost `div` fills the remaining height, accounting for the header and footer. In IE, the innermost `div` is the same height as the body, causing scroll bars.

Is there a cross browser way of generating such a layout?

Requirements: the innermost `div` must not have `display` set, the header must not have its height fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use techniques such as defining top, left, bottom and right at the same time.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/SD4nM/5/)

**Main CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 45px;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: That only works when the height of the header is known/fixed. Ideally, the header would size to fit its contents, and the content pane would fill the remaining space.